# Android: Double click in browser

Tags: android

How can I catch a double click in WebBrowser? I tried to find an anwer in other sites, but I found nothing.

I want to set zoom by double click.

How can I do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {

     // your custom way to zoom 
            return true;
        }


    });


    yourWebView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

    });
```